# Slow MQ Topic Subscription. Parallelization not improving performance

Tags: java, performance, jms, ibm-mq, mq

I am performing a number of wildcard subscriptions (e.g. /A/# and /B/#). Each subscription (see `createSubscriber(topic)` below) results in around 1000 Topics and takes around 10 seconds to return. Is 10 seconds a reasonable response time?  It seems slow to me, but I have nothing to compare it to.

Given the code below;

```
public class JMSClientSubscriber implements Runnable {

    TopicConnection           topicCon;
    Properties                properties;
    List<MyListener>          listeners;
    JmsTopicConnectionFactory jcf;
    boolean                   connected, alive;

    public JMSClientSubscriber() throws JMSException {
            properties = Properties.getInstance();
            listeners = new LinkedList<>();
            jcf = FLOWConnectionFactory.getTopicFactory(properties, Location.CLIENT);
            connected = false;
            alive = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                    connect();
                    while (alive) {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    void connect() throws Exception {
            connected = false;
            topicCon = jcf.createTopicConnection();

            topicCon.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
                    @Override public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
                            disconnect();
                            try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    connect();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            });

            topicCon.start();

            for (MyListener listener: listeners) { 
                    Thread t = new Thread() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                    TopicSession topicSes;
                                    try {
                                            topicSes = topicCon.createTopicSession(false, Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                                            Topic topic = topicSes.createTopic(listener.exampleMessage.getTopicSubscription());
                                            System.out.println(new Date() + " Subscribing to " + topic);
    /* THIS TAKES 10 SECONDS! */            TopicSubscriber topicSub = topicSes.createSubscriber(topic);
                                            System.out.println(new Date() + " Subscription finished " + topic);
                                            topicSub.setMessageListener(listener);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                    };
                    t.start();
            }
            connected = true;
    }

    void disconnect() {
            try {
                    connected = false;
                    if (topicCon != null) topicCon.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {}    
    }

    public void stop() { alive = false; }

    public class MyListener implements MessageListener {           
            Class<? extends FlowMessage>       expectedClass;
            FlowMessage                        exampleMessage;

            public MyListener(Class<? extends FlowMessage> expectedClass) throws Exception {
                    this.expectedClass = expectedClass;
                    exampleMessage = expectedClass.newInstance();
                    listeners.add(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message arg0) {
                    BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage) arg0;

                    try {
                            byte bytes[] = new byte[(int) bm.getBodyLength()];
                            bm.readBytes(bytes);
                            FlowMessage flowMessage = exampleMessage.newInstance(bytes);
                            System.out.println(new Date() + "[" + bm.getJMSDestination() + "] " + flowMessage.toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Properties properties = Properties.newInstance(new File("D:\\cc_views\\D253570_ALL_FLOW_DEV\\DealingRoom\\FLOW\\src\\cfg\\flow.properties"));
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream(properties.getPropertyAsFile("logging.properties")));

            /* Thread per connection */
            for (Class<FlowMessage> clazz: new Class[] { KondorCpty.class, KondorPair.class }) {
                    JMSClientSubscriber s = new JMSClientSubscriber();
                    s.new MyListener(clazz);
                    new Thread(s).start();
            }

            /* Thread per session */
            JMSClientSubscriber s = new JMSClientSubscriber();
            s.new MyListener(KondorCpty.class);
            s.new MyListener(KondorPair.class);
            new Thread(s).start();

    }
```

}

The `main` in this code runs two tests;

One Connection + Multi Thread/Sessions

```
Tue Sep 13 10:18:50 2016 Subscribing to topic://DRS/OW/Cpty/#
Tue Sep 13 10:18:50 2016 Subscribing to topic://DRS/OW/Pair/#
Tue Sep 13 10:19:00 2016 Subscription finished topic://DRS/OW/Cpty/#
Tue Sep 13 10:19:07 2016 Subscription finished topic://DRS/OW/Pair/#
Tue Sep 13 10:19:08 2016[topic://DRS/OW/Pair/RONGBP] KondorPair
```

Multi-thread Connection + One Session per Thread/Connection

```
Tue Sep 13 10:22:42 2016 Subscribing to topic://DRS/OW/Pair/#
Tue Sep 13 10:22:42 2016 Subscribing to topic://DRS/OW/Cpty/#
Tue Sep 13 10:22:52 2016 Subscription finished topic://DRS/OW/Cpty/#
Tue Sep 13 10:23:00 2016 Subscription finished topic://DRS/OW/Pair/#
Tue Sep 13 10:23:00 2016[topic://DRS/OW/Pair/RONGBP] KondorPair
```

Both tests are the same timing-wise and behavior wise.

- Subscriptions for ~1000 topic takes ~10 seconds
- Subscriptions seem to run sequential, even though they are in different threads.
- Topic updates only appear after ALL Subscriptions are complete.
- Having TopicConnection.start() before or after Subscriptions makes not difference in performance or when the first Topic update arrives.

So how do I speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following:

1) For every createSession (queue or topic) method invocation, data flows from both client and queue manager for setting up JMS Session environment. You are using remote connection which means there is data flow over network is involved.

2) The createSubscriber method invocation involves creation of subscription object, temporary queue apart from topic look up, authority validations etc at queue manager end.

Can you show us how you are parallelizing connections/sessions?

As per JMS specifications, a session should not be shared across threads. I would dedicate one thread for each subscriber where the thread

1) Creates JMS Connection

2) Creates a JMS Session

3) Creates a subscriber

4) Does JMS Connection.start() to start message delivery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. I have included the full code.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to move the topicCon.start() after the subscribers are created and listeners are setup. That ensures listeners are ready to receive messages when connection.start() is called to tell the messaging provider to start delivering messages.

Comment: I tried this. No change. Still (a) each subscription takes 10 seconds to return and (b) the first Topic update is only received after the final subscription is complete. (FYI - I am using MQClient 7.5 JARs, with Java8).

Comment: I will try executing your code and update when I have some result

Comment: Hi, I think that the Threading is doing more harm than good. I ran `TopicConnection.start()` first, then the `createSubscriber` in a `for` loop. Here, the Topic updates for the first subscription are being read by it's `MessageListener`, while the next `createSubscriber` is being run.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in `onMessage`. Instead of dealing with the message here, I put the message on a `BlockingQueue`. A number of separate threads then polled this `BlockingQueue`. This greatly improved the throughput of the `MessageListener` and moved the multi-threading issue away from the JMS/MQ code.